# Store ViewBag after IView.Render

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using this function to render view into a string:

```
protected virtual string RenderViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    ViewData.Model = model;

    if (viewName == null)
        viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);

        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

In my view i set some ViewBag variables (title, for example) like:

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Some title"; }
```

but `viewContext.ViewBag` is empty, for example

```
viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
var title = viewContext.ViewBag.Title; // null
```

How i can get changed in view `ViewBag`?

Comment: `ViewBag` works in one direction. Use `TempData` or `Session`

Comment: Use a mutable model.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin `TempData` saves data from previous request. For example, `@TempData["title"]; TempData["title"] = "some title";` first request - will write none (null), second - "some title"